# Can not add library after import project from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, build.gradle

I have recently imported project from Eclipse to Android Studio and now I am trying to add third-part library to my project in Android Studio, and here is my problem.

My code is below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'){
    force = true
}
compile 'com.sromku:simple-fb:4.0.6'
compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.2.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.4.1-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/FlurryAgent.jar')
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
}
```

In this case I have a problem with adding 'com.sromku:simple-fb:4.0.6'. 
On each sync Android Studio is displaying this message:

```
Error:(8, 13) Failed to resolve: com.sromku:simple-fb:4.0.6
```

My top-level build.gradle file is:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
}
}
```

Any idea how to resolve this problem?

---

After long reasearch I find the solution ;)

As you see on the this image 
[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6k7C.png)  after importing project to Android Studio in Project Structure field "Default Library Repository" was empty. When I have filled it with the same text as Android Plugin Repository field evrything have started working ;)

Enjoy ;)

Comment: If there is another android project/module which gives you access to com.sromku:simple-fb api's then, you need to import that module or add as library

Comment: Are you using local maven? Post your top-level build.gradle file

Comment: I put build.gradle top level file in post above.

Comment: Solution describe in post ;)